# How to solve second order ODE from a simplified version of the two-body problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

While thinking about the motion of a particle being attracted to another massive particle  and considering that the acceleration of that particle is not constant, I found myself trying to solve this equation $$\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{f(t)^2}.$$

This is how I got there:

$m_1$ is the mass of particle 1 and $m_2$ is the mass of particle 2 which we will consider to be much larger than $m_1$. Both particles are at rest at t=0.

Newton's law gives us:
$F=ma$

$F=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r(t)^2}$ Let r be the distance between the two bodies.

We assume here that the movement of the particle with mass $m_2$ with respect to a stationary point is negligible.

$m_1\frac{dr(t)^2}{dt^2}=G\frac{m_1m_2}{r(t)^2}$

$\frac{dr(t)^2}{dt^2}=G\frac{m_2}{r(t)^2}$

I believe that all of this is a modified version of the two-body problem. Hopefully, the solution will be slightly simpler.

This all leads us to the original question of how to solve:

$\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{f(t)^2}$

Comment: [Related math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750166/is-there-any-general-function-xt-that-gives-the-solution-to-xt-k-xt/750238#750238)

Comment: Note that your equation of motion should be $\ddot{r} = - G m_2/r^2$ if you want to have an attractive gravitational force (and $r > 0$.)

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Doesn't the sign just depend on our coordinate system?

Comment: If you want the object to represent an object accelerating under a gravitational force, and $r$ to represent the distance from the origin (which we normally take to be positive), then you need to have $\ddot{r} < 0$ and so you need the negative sign.  There's not a lot of freedom in that coordinate choice; inverting $r \to - r$ means that $r$ becomes the negative of the distance to the origin, which is weird, and you can't translate $r \to r + d$ without also changing the form of the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: The DE has a solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5By%28x%29%5D%5E2+y%27%27%28x%29%3D1 but it can be rendered explicit in $ft)$ ($y(x)$)

Comment: You **need** the negative sign to make the force attractive. With the negative sign, this is the radial Kepler equation. You can find an explicit solution for time as a function of radial distance.